# Android data lost on theme change (Light/Dark mode)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-theme

**Android**: I have made a simple `Todo` list app using `Kotlin`. And the theme (Light/Dark) of this app is set to system default theme `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`. Now the problem is that when I changed theme to `Dark` mode(because my emulator's theme was set to `Light` theme previously), all added Todo items were gone and same when I changed to `Light` mode again. Then I noticed the size of my `ArrayList` became `0` (empty).

Here is screenshots to understand it better:

*Light Mode*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWbzO.png

after changing system theme to Dark

*Dark Mode*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9iqg.png

tasks are added to `list: ArrayList` when `saveButton: Textview` is clicked

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var modified = false
    private lateinit var listView: ListView
    private lateinit var input: EditText
    private lateinit var saveButton: TextView
    private lateinit var cancelButton: TextView

    private val list = ArrayList<String>()
    private lateinit var listAdapter: CustomAdapter
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
        input = findViewById(R.id.input)
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn)
        cancelButton = findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn)

        listAdapter = CustomAdapter(this, list)
        listView.adapter = listAdapter

        val warningToast = Toast.makeText(this,
            "The text may be empty or contains only spaces",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            val text = input.text.toString()
            // if text is empty or only contains blank
            if (text.isEmpty() || text.isBlank()) {
                warningToast.show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            if (!modified) {
                // output list size 0 after changing theme 
                Log.d("MY_DEBUG", "size fo list is : ${list.size}")
                list.add(input.text.toString())
            } else {
                // ...
            }
            input.text.clear()
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
       
        // ...

    }
}
```

I thought that this is because it triggers a `uiMode` configuration change when theme mode is changed. So, the activity is recreated automatically. I want to keep added items even after changing theme. Is there any way to prevent loss of added items. Thank you!

Comment: Use a `ViewModel`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `ViewModel`. Thanks it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing theme recreates your activity and it reinitiates your `list`. It is not because of changing theme itself.

You have to save your data persistently, in a database or in a SharedPreferences instance with your own serialization method (like JSON).